# Get hash of arrays content inside a subroutine

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a hash of array like this which i want to use inside a subroutine. I pass it by reference to this subroutine like the `&sub(\%hash)` and inside sub i do this `print Dumper $_[0]` and this is my output :

```
$VAR1 = {
      'key1' => [
                              'value1',
                              'value2'
                            ],
      'key2' => [
                                          'foo',
                                          'bar'
                                        ]
    };
```

What is the proper way get the content of all array values into 2 separate arrays inside my subroutine like this :

```
my @ones ; my @tows ;
print "@ones" ;
print "\n"; 
print "@tows";
```

And get this in the output

```
value1 foo
value2 bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call your subroutine with a `&`. It'll just confuse you at some point and hasn't been necessary for almost twenty years.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash = (
  key1 => [
    'value1',
    'value2'
  ],
  key2 => [
    'foo',
    'bar'
  ]
);

print_vals(\%hash);

sub print_vals {
  my ($hashref) = @_;

  # $hashref->{key1} is a reference to an array
  # therefore @{$hashref->{key1}} is an array
  my @arr1 = @{$hashref->{key1}};
  my @arr2 = @{$hashref->{key2}};

  # $#arr1 is the last index in @arr1
  for (0 .. $#arr1) {
    say "$arr1[$_] $arr2[$_]"
  }
}
```

Comment: if my hash passed to this subroutine is the second argument how can i edit `my ($hashref) = @_;` ?

Comment: Why don't you see if you can work it out for yourself?

Comment: i found it by passing a hash reference and then assigning it to my hash like this `my $ref = $_[1] ;my %hashref = %$ref;`

Comment: Or you could do `my (undef, $hashref) = @_;` and leave the rest of the code unchanged. Incidentally, `%hashref` is a terrible name for that variable. It's a hash, not a hash reference.